# For a list with matrices inside an array format, is there a fast function for finding the consecutive column differences?

Tags: r

I have an list of 3 elements with an array of matrices inside:

```
> set.seed(1)
> A <- list(replicate(5, matrix(rnorm(22), nrow = 2)), replicate(5, matrix(rnorm(22), nrow = 2)),replicate(5, matrix(rnorm(22), nrow = 2)))
> A
[[1]]
, , 1

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]       [,7]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8356286  0.3295078 0.4874291  0.5757814 1.5117812 -0.6212406
[2,]  0.1836433  1.5952808 -0.8204684 0.7383247 -0.3053884 0.3898432 -2.2146999
            [,8]        [,9]     [,10]     [,11]
[1,]  1.12493092 -0.01619026 0.8212212 0.9189774
[2,] -0.04493361  0.94383621 0.5939013 0.7821363

, , 2

            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]        [,6]       [,7]
[1,]  0.07456498  0.61982575 -0.1557955 -0.4781501  1.3586796  0.38767161 -1.3770596
[2,] -1.98935170 -0.05612874 -1.4707524  0.4179416 -0.1027877 -0.05380504 -0.4149946
           [,8]      [,9]      [,10]     [,11]
[1,] -0.3942900 1.1000254 -0.1645236 0.6969634
[2,] -0.0593134 0.7631757 -0.2533617 0.5566632
    ......
```

I would like to use a fast function to go inside each matrix, within each of the three list elements, within each of the 5 arrays, and find the consecutive column by column difference. For example, for the first element in the first matrix, I would take the values in the first column and subtract them from the second. Going from:

```
> A[[1]][,c(1,2),1]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8356286
[2,]  0.1836433  1.5952808
```

to

```
> diff(t(A[[1]][,c(1,2),1]))
           [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -0.2091748 1.411637
```

I am not sure how to make it fast and scalable. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think `lapply(A, function(y) apply(y, 3, function(x) x[, -ncol(x)] - x[, -1]))` should be fast enough as the operations within `apply` are cheap

Comment: Runs about 8 sec on a 2GB list